# Xamarin Form WebView height as HTML content

Tags: webview, xamarin.forms

where I have a WebView that loads a html page with 3 gif .
I would like the WebView become as big as the HTML content . It's possible? 
Under the WebView I show some instructions inside a Label

```xml
   <Grid>
     <Grid>
       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <Grid Grid.Row="0" >
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         ...     
       </Grid>
       <Grid Grid.Row="1">
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <WebView x:Name="webw1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></WebView>
       </Grid>
       <Grid Grid.Row="2" >
         <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ScrollView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
           <Label Text="LastExplanation" x:Name="lblLastExplanation" />
         </ScrollView>
       </Grid>
     </Grid>
   </Grid>
 </ContentPage>
```

```cs
public FinalCheck()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  webw1.Source = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get() + "instruction.html";
}
```

Comment: You can inject a javascript function that returns the height of the HTML content on load event and then set the height of your webview with this height obtained.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way if it wont change:

`<WebView x:Name="webw1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HeightRequest="xxx"></WebView>`

OR

You can either create a custom renderer or create a way to communicate with you html page to send you data, in this situation height

[This](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/25967/setting-height-of-webview-dynamically) may help if it needs to be dynamic/interactive.